# GitLab и собственный Nginx

Tags: nginx, gitlab

Установил Gitlab, планируя настроить его на работу с уже установленным Nginx, однако второй просто не перенаправляет на приложение.

Настройку производил по документации GitLab'a, раздел "[Использование не встроенного веб-сервера](https://docs.gitlab.com/13.10/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server)" (в качестве Nginx конфигурации использовался [файл](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/-/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-ssl-nginx.conf) из официального репозитория) - результата нет.

Протокол используется HTTPS, редирект с HTTP на HTTPS осуществляется через CloudFlare.

**Решение**: Очистил кеш браузера и он стал перенаправлять в правильное место.

Конфигурация для будущих поколений:

1. Конфигурация GitLab: https://pastebin.com/UZk0L63E
2. Файл сервера в Nginx: https://pastebin.com/GWZk5sPC
3. Файл default в Nginx: https://pastebin.com/DRGt8M0P

Comment: Конфиг НЕ Гитлабовского Nginx в студию. То что я вижу `Файл default в Nginx` - это ничего. Вы или пропустили еще файлы, либо там действительно ничего нет, ну тогда вы вообще ничего не сделали в плане настройки Nginx. `nginx -T` выдаст весь конфиг - вот его приложите. Вот примерно что должно быть https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/-/tree/master/web-server/nginx

Comment: В вопросе писал, что как раз и использовал файл "gitlab-omnibus-ssl-nginx.conf" из официального репозитория GitLab, причём перепробовал все возможные варианты с ним:
1. Использовал файл полностью, заменив только "YOUR_SERVER_FQDN".
2. Использовал слегка сокращенную версию: https://pastebin.com/SH3Vxa0U

Comment: 3. Беря во внимание UPD1 пробовал так:  https://pastebin.com/DSDE9vMq
Никакого результата.

Comment: Пробовал как с подобной конфигурацией GitLab: https://pastebin.com/jquXQ48g
Так и с подобной: https://pastebin.com/sMCfvB0T

В общем, перепробовал все варианты - просто перенаправляет на сайт из default.

Comment: @TotalPusher Обновил пост, там текущая конфигурация.

Comment: Хорошо. Нужно понять, на каком этапе происходит ошибка, то есть ее локализовать. Либо Nginx на машине не может достучаться до http://gitlab-workhorse, либо в веб-сервере http://gitlab-workhorse что-то не так. 1) покажите что происходит при заходе на главную Гитлабы `curl -v http://адрес-гитлабы`. 2) что лежит в логах Nginx error_log и access_log. 3) мне не нравится `external_url "http://ngitlab.сайт.pro"` потому что это не FQDN из-за кириллицы, или вы это спецом заменили. И еще я не нашел конфиг гитлабы, там должны быть прописаны `trusted_proxies`

Comment: PS. гитлаба стартует не сразу, надеюсь вы выждали 2-5 минут. ну Nginx после исправления конфига нужно перегружать через `nginx -s reload` или `service nginx restart` или `service nginx reload` - на всякий случай уточняю

Comment: @TotalPusher 1) https://pastebin.com/j6Lxm00p 3) Специально заменил, чтобы не долбились, поменял на реальные значения, чтобы не путать ( по тем же ссылкам актуальная конфигурация ). 4) Вроде бы trusted_proxies не нужно писать, если nginx и gitlab стоят на одной машине? В любом случае, добавил в конфигурацию, актуальная версия в ссылках "Конфиг GitLab".

Comment: @TotalPusher Проверил access_log, не нашёл там запроса со своего IP. Очистил кеш браузера - всё заработало, благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в кеше браузера, после его очистки всё заработало правильно.

**Как понял?**: В логах `NGINX`, в файле `access_log`, не было запросов с моего IP адреса.

**Благодарности**: @TotalPusher за помощь в поиске проблемы.